# Is there a way to make ChkTeX ignore TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf, sourcecode, syntax-checker, chktex

[ChkTeX](http://baruch.ev-en.org/proj/chktex/) does not like TikZ, and will report a bunch of errors. Is there a way to make ChkTex ignore TikZ code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [the ChkTeX manual](http://tex.loria.fr/outils/ChkTeX.pdf#page=12), you can ignore the contents of an enivronment completely by adding its name to the `VerbEnvir` entry of the configuration file `.chktexrc`. So in order to not check PGF/TikZ environments, this file should look like this:

```
# Exclude these environments from syntax checking
VerbEnvir { pgfpicture tikzpicture }
```

Comment: Thanks - that was what I needed. Apparently it is only working if `.chktexrc` is in the folder from which chktex is run.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen It should work if `.chktexrc` is in your home directory.  I'm not sure if that works on Windows though.  You can always set the environment variable `CHKTEXRC` to point to the directory containing `.chktexrc`.

Comment: FWIW, I have include `tikzpicture` and `pgfpicture` as verbatim environments by default in the latest version of ChkTeX (which you'll have to compile yourself at the moment).